# Backbone: Move a model to another Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my first time using backbone, so I'm pretty confused about everything. I'm trying to make a todo list. Once I click "finished" on the todo, I want it to append to the "Completed" list.

I've been following this tutorial, and I tried to replicate the code(I tried to create a new completedTodo view and stuff like that), and I tried to do when clicking "finished" it would delete the $el, and I would add to the completedTodos. I think the problem here is even if it's added, it's not doing anything.

```
  done: function() {
var completed = new CompletedTodo({
  completedTask: this.$('.task').html(),
  completedPriority: this.$('.priority').html()
});
completedTodos.add(completed);
this.model.destroy();
```

},

I put in a debugger there to see if it actually added to the collection, and when i did completedTodos.toJSON();, it does give me back the new thing I just added.

However, it does not append to my collection list.

Here is my whole entire script file, in case I named anything wrong.

```
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    task: '',
    priority: ''
  }
});

var CompletedTodo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    completedTask: '',
    completedPriority: ''
  }
});

var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var todos = new Todos();

var CompletedTodos = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var completedTodos = new CompletedTodos();

//Backbone view for one todo
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: new Todo(),
  tagName: 'tr',
  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template($('.todos-list-template').html());
  },
  events: {
    'click .finished-todo': 'done',
    'click .delete-todo' : 'delete'
  },
  done: function() {
    var completed = new CompletedTodo({
      completedTask: this.$('.task').html(),
      completedPriority: this.$('.priority').html()
    });
    completedTodos.add(completed);
    this.model.destroy();
  },
  delete: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

//Backbone view for all todos
var TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: todos,
  el: $('.todos-list'), 
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html('');
    _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(todo) {
      self.$el.append((new TodoView({model: todo})).render().$el);
    });
    return this;
  }
});

//View for one Completed Todo
var CompletedTodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: new CompletedTodo(),
  tagName: 'tr',
  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template($('.completed-todos-template').html());
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

//View for all Completed Todos
var CompletedTodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: completedTodos,
  el: $('.completed-todos-list'), 
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html('');
    _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(completedTodo) {
      self.$el.append((new CompletedTodoView({model: completedTodo})).render().$el);
    });
    return this;
  }
});

var todosView = new TodosView();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-todo').on('click', function() {
    var todo = new Todo({
      task: $('.task-input').val(),
      priority: $('.priority-input').val()
    });
    $('.task-input').val('');
    $('.priority-input').val('');
    todos.add(todo);
  });
});
```

After this, I also have to figure out how to use Parse to make it persist to the database. I figured I'd get everything working in backbone first, and then try to do put in the database. I'm also suppose to use node/express, so would that help? I'm pretty much a Ruby on Rails kind of person, so I don't really know any of these javascript framework type of stuff.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

It was just because I didn't initialize the view.

```
var completedTodosView = new CompletedTodosView();
```

This fixed it.